# Do we need d&d 5e basic tags?

Tags: discussion

Wizards just announced D&D 5e basic which will be a free pdf. Should this be a seperate tag?

http://www.wizards.com/dnd/Article.aspx?x=dnd%2F4ll%2F20140527

Answer (score 11):

I don't think we can say yet, because we haven't seen what the Basic version looks like--and we probably *shouldn't* say, even then. We should wait until tags for it appear in the system, at which point we can start evaluating based on actual use rather than theory.

Comment: I agree. Tags should follow questions, not the other way around. Also, if Basic D&D ends up being a set of Quickstart rules, like [some games have](http://greenronin.com/dragon_age/about-dragon-age-rpg.php), then there's no reason for a separate tag.

Comment: What in the article is missing which makes you say we don't know what it will look like?   Do you think WoTC is lying about their product?

Comment: It's a little tangential, because of the second part of my answer, but--WotC doesn't have to deliberately *lie* in order to be inaccurate or incomplete in their description of an as-yet-unreleased product. They might wind up simplifying the rules or revising their vision entirely.

Comment: Agreed, tags are emergent and shouldn't be set up in advance

Answer (score 3):

1. Not in advance, tags are emergent
2. Probably not. Look, we have *some* versioned tags, mainly for D&D,  to reduce confusion, but there is such a thing as too much differentiation there. We don't have separate tags for Essentials, for playtests, for beginner boxes, etc. Normal games get away with a tag for the game, and ask in your question text if you really need it more precise. D&D gets big version buckets, but these really are intended to be "you know, the version of D&D published in a given decade" and not a tagging system designed to mimic the company's specific release schedule.  Major version is as far as tags do - or IMO should - go.

Comment: When did the essentials tag get merged?  http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/706/is-the-dnd-essentials-tag-really-appropriate-necessary?rq=1

Comment: @GMNoob A while ago. We need to know how different basic is from advanced before we decided to differentiate them

Comment: From the article, it sounds like it is consciously just the "SRD version" (an analogy since I'm sure they won't open license, sigh) of the main rules, and therefore not meaningfully different (he uses the analogy of the Rules Cyclopedia twice).

Comment: @waxeagle All basic rules will be in the advanced rules, as one of many possible options. Not all rules in the advanced rules will be in the basic rules.  So if somebody asks if they can do X, and it's an optional wording in the advanced rules but not in the basic, you'll get different answers depending on if they only have access to the free game or not. I recognize that tags are emergent though.

Comment: Not worth a new tag IMO, and if one emerges I'll be looking to advocate merging it unless there's some additional data that becomes available. Otherwise we'd have tags for everyone's beginner box etc - tags don't replace using your words in your question.

Comment: @GMNoob Unless they're incompatible versions, that is, different games, then it should be valid to say "no, but if you have access to book X, you also have options Y, Z, and W." We already answer questions like that for other editions of D&D that have rules/options scattered over a lot of for-pay books.